# angular unit testing and httpBackend.expectGET

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

New to the whole testing thing.  I got this running earlier today but one issue I was having was a GET error when I didn't include the following line:

```
httpBackend.expectGET('view/contents/home.html').respond(200, '');
```

What's the deal with this?  Why do I need this? The controller I'm testing has no reference to that file.  Can someone explain why it's trying to grab that template?

```
var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.projects']);

controllers.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, foo) { 
  $scope.currentStatus = null;


$scope.init = function (){
  foo.fn().then(function(status){
    $scope.currentStatus = status;
      });
  }

});

describe('Controllers:: Master.js', function () {

// load the controller's module
beforeEach(module('app'));

 var scope;
 var foo;
 var stateParams;
 var q;
 var deferred; 
 var rootScope;
 var httpBackend;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $q, _$httpBackend_) {

  foo = {
    fn: function() {
              deferred = $q.defer();
              deferred.resolve('bar');
              return deferred.promise;

            }
          };

  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  stateParams = {};
  q = $q;
  rootScope = $rootScope;
  httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  httpBackend.expectGET('view/contents/home.html').respond(200, ''); 
  $controller('MainCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    $stateParams:stateParams,
    foo: foo,
  });

}));

it('Should call foo fn', function() {
  spyOn(foo, 'fn').and.callThrough();
  scope.init();
  //deferred.resolve('foo');
  scope.$apply();
  expect(foo.fn).toHaveBeenCalled();

  expect(scope.currentStatus).toBe('bar');

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did more digging.  Apparently the error is tripped by using ui-router and calling $apply(which calls $digest()) within my test.  Adding this within my Describe block worked for me.

```
beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
}));
```

More info here: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212